# Boostrap 3 Navbar not showing previously hidden content on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 navbar on my page:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
             <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse invisible">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li>
                   ....
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

The `navbar-collapse` is set to `invisible` by default when the page loads. When certain conditions are met (eg. some value of a received JSON is true), I remove the `invisible` class. This works very well when the navbar is not collapsed (on large screens). On smaller devices, the button for expanding/collapsing the hidden content never shows (after the invisible class is removed). It is like the hidden content never existed.

I guess I have to force the navbar to recalculate itself when the `invisible` class is removed from the DOM. Is there a way how to do this?

I remove the class using `$('.navbar-collapse').removeClass('invisible')`

Comment: "When certain conditions are met, I remove the invisible class." How are you removing it? Media queries should suffice for this problem.

Comment: Are you removing the class using jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: Using `$('.navbar-collapse').removeClass('invisible')`

Comment: Yeah, that's your problem. Read into media queries because that's basically how the rest of Bootstrap works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: I don't get this. I thought media queries restrict some CSS properties based on the size of the viewport etc. The "conditions" I mean here are coming from JS. I mean I receive a JSON and then I decide whether the `invisible` class should be removed or kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the HTML for the mobile navigation button inside the `navbar-header` and the ID to attach it to the list items: (and probably add the `invisible` class to the `navbar-toggle` button.

See example with a dummy condition on viewport reduction.

Also, (depending on which version of Bootstrap you're using) use `navbar-right` instead of `pull-right`.

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  var viewportW = $(window).width();

  if ($(window).width() < 991) {

    $('.navbar-collapse, .navbar-toggle').removeClass('invisible');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed invisible" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>

    </button><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse invisible" id="bs-navbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li> <a href="#"> About</a>

      </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> Contact</a>

      </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> Products</a>

      </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> Blog</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```